# QEMU/KVM single file from Ubuntu host's shared folder not available in Windows guest

Tags: samba, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, file-sharing, qemu

I'm at a loss with the following setup:

My Ubuntu server runs a **native** QEMU/KVM based Windows 10 (no Virtualbox or alike!). Two folders of the server are shared with the Windows guest. Everything is fine but one single file that doesn't show up in the Windows guest. Moving or copying this file into another (shared) folder followed by a restart of the guest doesn't help. The file's attributes are identical to other files that are shared. What am I missing here...

```
uname -a 
Linux MW-TPW520 5.4.0-88-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 23 17:29:00 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Txs -mgw

Comment: What is the name of the file? If there are any special characters in the file name that are allowed in Linux but not in Windows or if the fine name ends with a dot, Windows won't recognize that file.

Comment: The filename complies to W* rules due to the fact that the original has been "produced" by the guest! But let me do a test...

Comment: I (1) renamed the file (2) copied it to root and back , always restarting the guest afterwards, to no avail. Creating a new file under Linux and updating the folder in Windows shows the expected result = new file shows up in the folder list.

Comment: It was worth a try. I have no more ideas. Best of luck!